# Get row Sums across multiple users/tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in SQL Server, and I have three tables that I have simplified below

USERS:

```
UserId  | FirstName | LastName  | Email
--------+-----------+-----------+------------------
1       |    Joe    | Johnson   | jjohnson@work.com
2       |   Mary    | Smith     | msmith@work.com
```

POINTS:

```
UserId  | PointsEarned
--------+--------------
1       |   25
2       |   50
1       |   50
1       |   10
2       |   20
```

CLAIMS:

```
UserId | PointsUsed
-------+-----------
1       |   50
2       |   20
1       |   10
1       |   10
2       |   5
```

I'm trying to run a report of distinct users with a sum of points earned and a sum of points used. I've started with the join of tables by userId...

```
SELECT  
    Users.UserId, Users.FirstName, Users.LastName, Users.Email, 
    Points.PointsEarned, Claims.PointsUsed
FROM
    Users 
INNER JOIN
    Points ON Points.UserId = Users.UserId 
INNER JOIN
    Claims ON Users.UserId = Claims.UserId
```

but of course that returns the user multiple times, I've tried many variations of Group By, Distinct, etc but can't seem to get there. Users are (in theory) already distinct by Id or email, the entries into the other two tables are dozens up to hundreds per user.

Desired output would be something like this

```
UserId  | FirstName | LastName  | Email             | PointsEarned  | PointsUsed
1       |    Joe    | Johnson   | jjohnson@work.com |   85          |   70
2       |   Mary    | Smith     | msmith@work.com   |   70          |   25
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with subqueries and `LEFT JOINS` in case there are `Users` without points.

```
select u.userid, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email, p.pointsearned, c.pointsused
from [users] u
left join (Select userid,sum(pointsearned) as pointsearned from points group by userid) p on u.userid=p.userid
left join (Select userid,sum(pointsused) as pointsused from claims group by userid) c on u.userid=c.userid
order by u.userid, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email
```

Comment: This totally did it, just had to add to add p.pointsearned & c.pointsused to the Group By, but perfect solution. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server supports `APPLY` which is another approach to the problem:

```
SELECT  u.*, p.PointsEarned, c.PointsUsed
FROM Users u OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT SUM(p.PointsEarned) as PointsEarned
      FROM Points p
      WHERE p.UserId = u.UserId
     ) p OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT SUM(c.PointsUsed) as PointsUsed
      FROM Claims c
      WHERE u.UserId = c.UserId
     ) c;
```

This uses `OUTER APPLY`, so you get all users, even those with no points.  Use `CROSS APPLY` if you want only users that have both claims and points.

The advantage to this approach is performance.  It probably works better than two aggregations with joins (assuming there is an index on `UserId` in the tables).  It *definitely* works better if you are filtering the users in the outer query.

Comment: I think it would be exactly the same performance as a pre-aggregated join (like in @WAMLeslie 's answer) if there is indexing, SQL Server is perfectly capable transforming between joins and applys (aka correlated nested loop) and either query will get the same plan. I find the main advantage to this format is comprehension: for each outer row, do this calculation; rather than pre-aggregating and then joining.

Comment: Note that `CROSS APPLY` will not help to inner join unless you also `GROUP BY ()`, because you currently have a [scalar aggregate, not a vector aggregate](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/03/fun-with-aggregates.html)